# started.FATAL: Log statements out of sync: current test suite 'TestTarget.xctest' not exists

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, integration

I have a Jenkins build server for my iOS project. I configured a job with the XCode integration plugin to launch unit test, but an error occurred when the first test is been launched:

started.FATAL: Log statements out of sync: current test suite 'Target_Test.xctest' not exists

Has anyone seen this console log before? Thanks for help.

Jenkins version: 2.46.3
Xcode Integration plugin version: 2.0.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue today, apparently it was because I had **spaces in the product name of my test target**. I changed them by '-' and now it seems working. Let me know if it was the same for you.